# Referring to specific df column when filtering for values in column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am removing outliers from my dataset and wanted to get some thoughts on efficient methods.

I am currently using IQR to filter out any outliers in my data as below:

```
Q1 = df.grades.quantile(0.25)
Q3 = df.grades.quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
```

Where the **grades** column in my df contains the values where I want to remove the outliers.

I have previous code used that does this but how can I edit code below, to account only for the grades column? (df.grades) and not just df

```
df = df[~((df < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(df > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=1)]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need remove `any` and test column `grades` like:

```
df = df[~((df.grades < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (df.grades > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR)))]
```